# How to find memory leaks on a linux-embedded system - non-x86 systems?

Tags: c, embedded, embedded-linux

I learnt that the valgrind can only be used for x86 platforms. How can I trace the memory leaks on my linux embedded system. Remember, the leak can both user and kernel space. What is the best way to track it down?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know who told you that about valgrind, because it is just wrong.

http://valgrind.org/info/platforms.html

Valgrind is well supported on many platforms...